# How to attribute rect to sprite

Tags: pygame

When I run this code it does not display the sprite on the screen . just a blank screen I have tried everything I can think of to get this to work .Some help would be much appreciated.

I have tried everything I can think of to get this to work. what I'm trying to do is create my sprites with a rect attribute.

```
import pygame
pygame.display.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

    x = 300
    y = 500
    x1 = 100
    y1 = 200
    image1 = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
    image1.image = pygame.image.load("picy.png").convert_alpha()
    image2 = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
    image2.image = pygame.image.load("picy1.png").convert_alpha()
    image1_rect = image1.image.get_rect(topleft=(x,y))
    image2_rect = image2.image.get_rect(topleft=(x1,y1))
    screen.blit(image2_rect,(x1,y1))
    screen.blit(image1_rect,(x,y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

I expect it to put my two sprites on the screen and when they touch for them to register a hit.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit):

> blit()
>   draw one image onto another
>   blit(source, dest, area=None, special_flags = 0) -> Rect
>   Draws a source Surface onto this Surface. The draw can be positioned with the dest argument. Dest can either be pair of coordinates representing the upper left corner of the source. A Rect can also be passed as the destination and the topleft corner of the rectangle will be used as the position for the blit. The size of the destination rectangle does not effect the blit.

The `blit` method takes as first argument a `Surface`, not a `Rect`. The `Surface` is your image.
Try with:

```
screen.blit(image2.image, dest=image2_rect)
screen.blit(image1.image, dest=image1_rect)
```

By the way, you may also wish to make the rectangles attributes of the `Sprite` instances, instead of separate instances:

```
image1.rect = image1.image.get_rect(topleft=(x,y))
image2.rect = image2.image.get_rect(topleft=(x1,y1))
```